# How to display multiple polygons on leaflet through psql-node-react

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, react

Want to display multiple polygons extracted from postgres database to leaflet map. However, no result shows on the map. My guess is that something wrong with geojson.

my server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const pool = require("./db");
const cors = require("cors");
const database=require("./database")


//middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

//Selecting the geometry in a geojson format 
app.get("/geom", async(req, res)=> {
try {
//create geojson format from the original table "cfl.kc_2010_bg"
  const geom=await pool.query("SELECT row_to_json(fc) AS st_asgeojson FROM (SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features FROM (SELECT 'Feature' As type, ST_AsGeoJSON(st_transform(geom,4326))::json As geometry,row_to_json((entid,name)) As properties FROM cfl.kc_2010_bg As lg) As f ) As fc;"
  );
  res.json(geom.rows);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
console.log("server is running on port 5000"); 
});
```

My leaflet.js

```
import { React, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, LayersControl, GeoJSON } from "react-leaflet";
//It is important to import leaflet styles in your component
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
const MyData = () => {
 
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/geom");
       
      const jsonData= response[0].st_asgeojson
      setData(jsonData)


    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);
  console.log(data);

  // render react-leaflet GeoJSON when the data is ready
  if (data) {
    return <GeoJSON data={data} />;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};


// Using the GeoJSON tag in a Map container
const LeafletMap = () => {

  const [center, setCenter] = useState({ lat: 38.9823, lng: -94.68919 });
  const zoomLevel = 14;
  return (
    <MapContainer center={center} zoom={zoomLevel}>
      {/*The LayersControl tag help us organize our layers into baselayers and tilelayers*/}
      <LayersControl position="topright">
        {/*Using an open street map basemap as a basemap*/}
        <LayersControl.BaseLayer name="OpenStreetMap" checked>
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
        </LayersControl.BaseLayer>
        <LayersControl.Overlay name="My GeoJSON layer" checked>
          <MyData />
        </LayersControl.Overlay>
      </LayersControl>

    </MapContainer>
  );
};
export default LeafletMap;
```